# Github SSH auth fails when pushing from a container using VS Code with Remote Containers plugin on Windows

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, containers, ssh-keys

I'm rather new to containerization. I have used Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL) to make an image containing for example Debian and Node JS.
I've followed these steps to [Add a new SSH Key to Your GitHub Account instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) to add a (private) SSH key *inside* the container (and add that public key to my GitHub account). Was it right to do that inside the container, basically using the terminal in VS Code?

I was able to pull and use this image on MacOS and was able to use the Source Control tab within VS Code (Running Remote-Development Plugin and opened my GitHub repository in my docker container.)

However on Windows, I am unable to use the Source Control tab in VS Code (while running connected to the dev container) for pulling and pushing. I receive the following error.

[image]

I am able to push and pull if I use the terminal, rather than the UI, and provide the password for the SSH key. How do I make it not require this, as in MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

> I, and provide the password for the SSH key

There is no password, only a passphrase, if you have associated one at the creation of the private key.
I suggest you create one *without* passphrase for testing.

Also for testing, try in command line (before launching VSCode):

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

As long as you don't see a Welcome message, the key won(t work (in a container or outside).